# Menu displaying in multiple lines in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I am working on a website. The site works fine in Chrome but in IE, the menu is getting displayed in multiple lines. Please help out. Thanks

Css is,

```
#menu{
    margin-left: 353px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer (which is why it's a comment) but you shouldn't be using images for you main navigation in 2012. Especially when they're just text.

Comment: What does the container for the menu div look like? I'm guessing the problem is with the width of the menu div. Have you tried checking it using the IE developer tools and comparing it with Chrome?

Comment: @JeffSiver: Thanks, the problem was with the width of the div. I had not defined the width of the div. I just came back defining the width and it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves the issue, just increase the width of #menu by 50px-

```
#menu {
  width: 550px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. But, I had not assigned a width to it. How did you predict it to be 500px?

Comment: There was a width:500px to #menu in CSS - now you made it 600px. Good! :)

Comment: I had a menu `ul` without a width and sometimes the `li`'s would collapse into several rows until there was a mouseover event and everything lined up perfectly as a single row.  Adding a `min-width`  to the `ul` is not how I wanted it to work but in this case it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE on this machine but try adding:

```css
#menu a img {
    border: 0;
}
```

to your CSS.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the border issue. But, the navigation is still into multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu{
    margin-left: 353px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    width:550px;
}
```

Adding width solves the problem. Thanks